# Sharepoint workflow not updating

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I have written a workflow for that autofills a column in a sharepoint list. When I add a new entry nothing happens. However, if I go to another list and then return to the list with the workflow I can see that it has worked. I have set up the workflow to start when a new item is created, is there some other setting in the workflow to make it update instantly?

Answer (score 0):

No there is no. You should use SPItemEventReceiver instead and use ItemUpdating method. This is what works instantly and the workflow requires some time to start and it runs asynchronously. Furthermore workflows are heavy and you should avoid using them for very simple actions.

The sample code for an event receiver is

```
public class MyEventReceiver :SPItemEventReceiver
{
    public override void ItemUpdating(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        UpdateField(properties);
    }

    public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        UpdateField(properties);
    }

    private void UpdateField(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        EventFiringEnabled = false;

        var item = properties.ListItem;

        // do calculation here

        item.SystemUpdate(false); // this update that is most suitable for automatic updates

        EventFiringEnabled = true;
    }
}
```

And then add this event receiver to a list. I hope this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff728093.aspx) helps

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Sounds like a good way to go. However, I do not have visual studio. Is there a way to accomplish this with sharepoint designer?

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to add a Calculated column to your list if you cannot use Visual Studio. This way the hardest point is to define a formula that will takes data from other columns of the list item and performs a calculation. [link1](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/examples-of-common-formulas-HA001160947.aspx) and [link2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb862071.aspx) can give you more information on how to write a formula in the calculated column in SharePoint with no code.